# unexpected error parsing through json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

a small program that reads name from user input, looks for the name in json file, and either greets or saves user depending. if file is not found, creates file.:

```
import json as j
import sys
fn = 'usernames.json'


def loadnames(f):
    #load usernames to memory
    try:
        n = []
        with open(f, 'r') as fo:
            strings = j.load(fo)
            for s in strings:       #assuming that it won't be a whole string
                n.append(s)

        return n

    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open(f, 'w') as fo:
            pass
        sys.exit()

def getname():
    name = input("Name:\t")
    return name


names = loadnames(fn)
name = getname()


with open(fn, 'w') as fo:

    if name in names:
        print(f"Welcome back, {name}.")
    else:
        print(f"We don't know you, {name}. We will save you to the list.")
        names.append(name)
        for n in names:
            j.dump(n, fo)
```

output(when file exists):

```
└─$ python3 rememberme.py                                                                                      1 ⨯
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/salt/Desktop/py/rememberme.py", line 57, in <module>
    names = loadnames(fn)
  File "/home/salt/Desktop/py/rememberme.py", line 42, in loadnames
    strings = j.load(fo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

not sure I understand this error.. what is this error about?

Comment: can you share the JSON file?

Comment: @charmful0x it's practically empty until it saves input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading file as a json file but when creating file you are not creating a valid json file, an empty json file should have at-least {}. So when you are trying to load json is complaining that it is expecting some valid json data in file. Similarly you can't keep just name in json file it should be key value pair. Best way to do what you are trying to do is create a file with names = empty list and then keep appending names to the list. I have modified your code a bit to make it work the way you want.

```
import json as j
import sys
fn = 'usernames.json'


def loadnames(f):
    #load usernames to memory
    try:
        with open(f, 'r') as fo:
            json_file = j.load(fo)
        return json_file.get('names')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open(f, 'w') as fo:
            fo.write('{"names": []}')
        return []
        #sys.exit()

def getname():
    name = input("Name:\t")
    return name


names = loadnames(fn)
name = getname()


with open(fn, 'w') as fo:

    if name in names:
        print(f"Welcome back, {name}.")
    else:
        print(f"We don't know you, {name}. We will save you to the list.")
        names.append(name)
    json_file = {}
    json_file['names'] =  names
    j.dump(json_file, fo)
    fo.close()




Output ::
python3 test.py
Name:   Taj
We don't know you, Taj. We will save you to the list.

python3 test.py
Name:   Uddin
We don't know you, Uddin. We will save you to the list.

python3 test.py
Name:   Taj
Welcome back, Taj.

python3 test.py
Name:   Uddin
Welcome back, Uddin.
```

Comment: is there a particular reason for `return []`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise program will crash at line "if name in names:" saying None type object is not iterable and you will have to put special check for None.

Comment: Oh,,,, ok. So if `loadnames()` goes wrong, program will still continue to the end since `sys.exit` is now `return []`, which `[]` will soon be value of `names` which will soon be tested in `if name in names:`.. Makes sense

Comment: Just to add.. what does `return json_file.get('names')` return exactly? According to [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) it will return the value of a key is specified, but in this case it is multiple values in a key. Does it return a list of the values?

Comment: get is a dict class method, it will return whatever value is present for the key "names" in json dictionary. in this case it will return names list.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the first character of the string is not in JSON.
This error also happens when an empty string is passed to decode.

You can handle this error like this:

```
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

def loadnames(f):
    #load usernames to memory
    try:
        n = []
        with open(f, 'r') as fo:
            strings = j.load(fo)
            for s in strings:       #assuming that it won't be a whole string
                n.append(s)

        return n

    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open(f, 'w') as fo:
            pass
        sys.exit()
    
    except JSONDecodeError:
      pass
```